# Using Rouché's theorem to infer the amount of zeroes inside the given domain

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

Given $p(z)=i z^{5}-8 z^{4}-\pi$,

How many zeros there is for $p(z)$ inside $ D_{1}(0) \cap\{z \mid \operatorname{Im}(z)>0\}$?

I can use Rouché theorem to infer how many zeros there are in the whole unit disk, but how do I infer the amount of zeros in the given domain?

Comment: can you show us how you applied Rouche's theorem for the unit disc? Because I'm sure using similar reasoning you can get the answer for this domain (I mean you just have to verify the hypotheses of Rouche's theorem are satisfied in this case).

Comment: $|iz^5 -  \ pi|< |-8z^4|$ for every $|z|=1$

Comment: Maybe if you use $8z^4+\pi$ as the comparison function (for which one knows roots also btw) which is big both on the real axis where $z^4 \ge 0$ and on the unit disc where it is at least $8-\pi$ works better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(z) = 8z^4 + \pi$. Then on the unit disk we have
$$
|iz^5| = 1 < 8 - \pi \leq |8z^4 + \pi| \leq |iz^5-8z^4-\pi| + |8z^4+\pi|.
$$
Then, on the real axis in $(-1, 1)$ we have
$$
|iz^5| < \pi \leq |8z^4 + \pi| \leq |iz^5-8z^4-\pi| + |8z^4+\pi|.
$$
Since there are 2 zeros of $g$ in $\mathbb{D} \cap \mathbb{H}$, we know that there are 2 zeros of $p$ in $\mathbb{D} \cap \mathbb{H}$ aswell.

Comment: in the first equality, you probably meant $|iz^5|=1<\cdots$

Comment: Why are the last inequalities needed? Is it not only necessary to show $|iz^5|<|g(z)|$ on both arcs?

Comment: 1. Haha yes I did mean $=1$, thanks for pointing it out.

2. The last inequality is not needed for the specific version of Rouche's theorem. The generalized version requires for two functions $f, g \in H(D)$ that $|f(z) + g(z)| < |f(z)| + |g(z)|$.